# Create a log of successful logins

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to create a log with successful logins and denied logins. I must save user that try access.

I don't know if `hook_user_login` is the correct way to do this task.

Appreciate any guidance to investigate. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for grammar checking

Comment: I don't know who voted to close, but this is a question that can be answered. In fact, I answered it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Also it is programming related. Sometimes I wonder if people just close-vote questions to get their badges...

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and I do not know if I've done something wrong. @ kiamlaluno has given me a wonderful response, I voted positively and I'm grateful to @ kiamlaluno. Forgive my poor English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hook_user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) is only invoked when a user successfully logs in.

The hook you should implement is [hook_watchdog()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7).

```
function hook_watchdog(array $log_entry) {
  switch ($log_entry['message']) {
    case 'Login attempt failed for %user.':
      // Somebody tried logging in as $log_entry['variables']['%user'],
      // and failed.
      break;

    case 'Session opened for %name.':
      // The login for $log_entry['variables']['%name'] was successful.
      break;
  }
}
```

Notice that:

- Both `$log_entry['variables']['%user']` (for when the login failed) and `$log_entry['variables']['%name']` (for when the login was successful) are usernames, not the user object.
- When the login was successful, `$log_entry['user']` is the user object for the user who right logged in, an `$log_entry['uid'] is the user ID.
- The other variables that could be helpful are:

  - `$log_entry['request_uri']`
  - `$log_entry['referer']`
  - `$log_entry['ip']`
  - `$log_entry['timestamp']`
- Drupal already keeps a log of those events in admin/reports/dblog; you simply need to filter them by type (user).

  [image: screenshot]

  There could be a reason to implement `hook_watchdog()` to keep a log for any failed/successful login, though: The database log is limited to N entries (where N could be 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, basing on what set on admin/config/development/logging), and it is for all the messages passed to [watchdog()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7); once the limit is reached, the old messages are lost.

Comment: Thank you very much. thanks to your good answer I understood many things. I'm starting with drupal and find people who know so much and is so kind to answer in detail is a pleasure. thank you again :)